# my..kalanchoe is dying

Tags: kalanchoe

[image]

It started like this at first (13 January 2023) [image]

Then I placed it on a dining table near sunlight. My older sibling (when II was at school) saw it kind of ?? I don't know decaying and put it under a table a bit too near the sun and she told me it burned !!!!

We put it in our kitchen also near a window but it has translucent curtains.

Then it started looking like this and so we decided to put it in my room on a table not too near and not too far from my window.

Some (not much) of the leaves are turning brown and the flowers are dying. Is this normal? What should I do  !!! my sibling watered it yesterday and actually every 2 days ???? because she tested the soil and it was dry.

If I do need to cut some of it how do I do it? This is my first time caring for a flower.

Comment: I don't know much about this type of plant. Is it possible the flowers are just at the end of their cycle and are drying off normally? The leaves look OK.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hybrid kalanchoe and is a succulant. And I found it hard to maintain this plant than their counterparts (the non-hybrid ones).

In the first picture, I can't see the flowers properly. After blooming these a single flower stays 4-5 days as far as I remember. After that it withers away. So, you have to check that.

When these flowers die, the stem does not droop like that immediately, they stand tall. So, the leaves may look okay, but I think there may be some problem.

Check the soil, drainage etc. If you had watered it regularly when the soil was still wet, it could have damaged roots. Don't over water it (this is a tricky thing for this hybrid plant which I  could not figure out). Cut off those dying flower stems to give some relief to the plant. Keep it at a bright spot. This is as far as I can say.

Good luck.